# django view to display the model form in a template

Tags: python, django

I've created a model form.I'd like to display it on webpage and push the form data into the database: below is model and the view. Here the topic_id and the command_id should be auto-generated by the db. Please let me know if the view I've created is correct.

Thanks,
Arun

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
# Create your models here.
from django.forms import ModelForm

class Topics(models.Model):
    topic_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    topic_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.name

class Command(models.Model):
    command_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    command = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    topic_under=models.ForeignKey(Topics)
    def _unicode_(self):
        return self.name

class TopicsForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Topics

class CommandForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Command
```

**views.py**

```
# Create your views here.
from command.models import Command
from command.models import CommandForm
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.context_processors import csrf

def submitform(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CommandForm()
        if form.is_valid():
           form.save()
           return render(request, 'newcommand.html')
    else:
        form = CommandForm()
        return render(request, 'inputtest.html', {'form': form})
```

Answer (score 3):

In the following block:

```
form = CommandForm()
if form.is_valid():
   form.save()
   return render(request, 'newcommand.html')
```

Replace `form = CommandForm()` with `form = CommandForm(request.POST)`

That will solve it.
Anyways, you should try generic class based views, since they are more powerful and standard.
You can learn about them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/).
Take a look at ListView, CreateView, UpdateView and DeleteView (a.k.a. CRUD)

Comment: Alvaro, Thanks for replying. I'ts only for a simple application